# PDOException error in mysql SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following 2 inserts on my database, with following code:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO order(order_id,user_id,product_id,sku,product_name,currency,price,quantity,options,value) VALUES (:orderid,:userid,:productid,:sku,:productname,:currency,:price,:quantity,:options,:value)";                                          
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    //options
    $options = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION['color'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['color'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['color'.$i]);}
    if(isset($_SESSION['density'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['density'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['density'.$i]);}
    if(isset($_SESSION['diameter'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['diameter'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['diameter'.$i]);}
    if(isset($_SESSION['flavor'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['flavor'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['flavor'.$i]);}
    if(isset($_SESSION['holepitch'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['holepitch'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['holepitch'.$i]);}
    if(isset($_SESSION['size'.$i]) && !empty($_SESSION['size'.$i])) {array_push($options, $_SESSION['size'.$i]);}

    $stmt1->bindParam(':orderid', $ordernumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);      
    $stmt1->bindParam(':userid', $UserID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':productid',  $_SESSION['pid'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':sku', $_SESSION['sku'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':productname',$_SESSION['itemname'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt1->bindParam(':currency',$currency, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $stmt1->bindParam(':price', $_SESSION['price'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt1->bindParam(':quantity', $_SESSION['quantity'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt1->bindParam(':options', $options[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $stmt1->bindValue(':value', $_SESSION['quantity'.$i] * $_SESSION['price'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);                             
    $stmt1->execute(); 


    //insert 2

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO shipping_cost(order_id,shipping_option,shipping_cost ) VALUES (:orderid,:shippingoption,:shippingcost)";                                          
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);                                         
    $stmt2->bindParam(':orderid', $ordernumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
    $stmt2->bindParam(':shippingoption', $shippingoption, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
    $stmt2->bindParam(':shippingcost', $shippingcost, PDO::PARAM_STR);                               
    $stmt->execute(); 
    } //end for
```

The above query resulted in the following PDOException with message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(order_id,user_id,product_id,sku,product_name,currency,price,quantity,optio' at line 1'

I am unable to understand what is wrong with the PDO statement above.

Requesting help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword. You have to quote it with backticks.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario ..Thank you very much...I missed it and never thought about it.

Comment: A little tip: try your queries directly on MySQL, with your favourite MySQL client. That allows to discard PHP issues.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Thank you for the tip.